# using objectFit in gatsby-image props

Tags: gatsby

I'm trying to use this property on gatsby-image: `objectFit="none"`
its having no effect - the default of `"cover"` appears instead.

I can fix this with css, but hoping there's no need to do this, any ideas.

Here's the code for the image:

```
    <Img
        fluid={product.variants[imageLoc].image.localFile.childImageSharp.fluid}
        objectFit="none"
    />
```

Answer (score 13):

Note that the `objectFit` & `objectPosition` props are only used if you are using the [IE polyfill version](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/tree/master/packages/gatsby-image#polyfilling-object-fitobject-position-for-ie):

```
import Img from "gatsby-image/withIEPolyfill" //<-- IE polyfill

<Img
  fixed={...}
  objectFit="cover"
  objectPosition="50% 50%"
/>
```

If not, you should pass them in as regular styles via `imgStyle`:

```
import Img from "gatsby-image" //<-- regular

<Img
  fixed={...}
  imgStyle={{
    objectFit: "none",
    objectPosition: "50% 50%",
  }}
/>
```

Comment: Thanks - that doesn't get explained at all in the documentation here: https://www.gatsbyjs.org/packages/gatsby-image, perhaps i'm missing something and its somewhere else. Perhaps the documentation needs updating.